# Moveable type images not displayed

Tags: apache

I installed Moveable type on a ubuntu box.
The admin section works great. 
However the front page does not. The images and CSS are not displayed.
This is coming from the apache error log:

```
Permission denied: exec of '/var/www/mt/example/styles.css' failed
Premature end of script headers: styles.css
```

I think it's related to my apache config. Since i call the admin section using the localhost, but i use the example.com for the front page, which is the part that doesnt work.
This is my apache config:

```
NameVirtualHost *
<VirtualHost *>
        ServerAdmin chris@example.com
        ServerName mt.example.net
        DocumentRoot /var/www/mt

        Alias /mt-static /var/www/mt/mt-static
        <Directory /var/www/mt/mt-static>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias / /var/www/mt/
        <Directory /var/www/mt>
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *>
        ServerAdmin chris@example.com
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAlias example.com www. example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/example

        Alias /mt-static /var/www/mt/mt-static
        <Directory /var/www/mt/mt-static>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
        Redirect /mt.cgi http://mt.example.net/mt.cgi
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

it because the directory where the css file is located (`var/www/mt/example/`) is a sub-directory of one which is declared to be a script in (`/var/www/mt`) with Options `+ExecCGI`

Directories inherit the options of their parents

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like Apache has tried to run the .css file as an executable. The only thing which I can suggest is that you might have a css file which has an executable permission, for some reason, so Apache tries to execute it. Try

```
chmod a-x
```

on the CSS file and see if it makes a difference.

Sometimes files copied from Windows have executable set when they shouldn't.